# Android: Only retrieve contacts with numbers

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I currently have the following code to retrieve contacts from the address book:

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
    };
    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '1'";
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, null, sortOrder); 

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, 
            cursor, 
            new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.Contacts._ID}, 
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1},0);
    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

However this also returns my facbook contacts on my Nexus 4. Is there an issue with my selections?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can filter your query results to only include contacts with a phone number by adding `ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER` to both your projection and selection.

Change your second and third statements to look something like this:

```
String[] PROJECTION = { 
ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, 
ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, 
ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
};
String selection = "(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + 
" = '1' AND (" + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " != 0 ))";
```

And the resulting cursor will only contain contacts with a phone number.

Comment: Turns out I had to add it to my Selection as well. Thanks!

Comment: You're right you need to add it to the selection too. I just updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

If think it's a normal behaviour, since your Facebook contacts are basically... Contacts, so they are retrieved by your code.
I think the best way to filter that is to loop through returned data and remove the ones without number.